# Navbar toggle doesn't work in my angular component

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

> Do someone see problem? I tried with replacing position of bootstrap
> and jquery imports in this html. This work in online html renderer. Does this have some relation with angular?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse ">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbarToggler" data-toggle="collapse"><span
                            class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand">PROJECT</a>
                </div>


                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggler">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a>Home</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a  href=""><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>Download</a></li>
                        <li><a  href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>
                                Login</a></li>
                        <li><a  href="register"><span
                                    class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Register</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" (click)="logout()"> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If this is your `.component.html`, then the scripts will be removed during compile time

Comment: It is. Do you know how to include them? @SagarV

Comment: You need to import them in your `index.html` file or `angular.json` file.

Comment: You're welcome. It's also recommended not to add `jQuery` in an angular project. Try to use `ng-bootstrap` if you intend to use `bootstrap` in your project.